# Изменение стиля var_dump`а

Tags: php

Можно ли как то изменить стиль var_dump, например выделить жирным ключ массива и т.д.?
Я конечно понимаю, что можно сделать javascript`ом, но хочется узнать возможно ли это на php, может в нём по легче можно это сделать.

Comment: а кто мешает свой написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легче всего это сделать через [xdebug.overload_var_dump](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#overload_var_dump).

> By default Xdebug overloads var_dump()
> with its own improved version for
> displaying variables when the
> html_errors php.ini setting is set to
> 1. In case you do not want that, you can set this setting to 0, but check
> first if it's not smarter to turn off
> html_errors.

Comment: Спасибо, но я не понял как с ним работать?

Comment: Просто подключить расширение xdebug. После этого `var_dump()` будет, так сказать, более наглядный. 

Правда настраивать внешнее отображение никак нельзя, разве что только через css.

Comment: @ilyaPirogov как быть если OpenServer не реагирует на изменение значения этого параметра?

Answer (score 0):

Неа, нельзя.

Можешь сам написать с использованием while или foreach. :) ну и там вывод стилями прописать

Comment: Спасибо, можно ещё как то так, а там уже обработать preg_match, но это уже получиться также как и на js, зато так удобней, когда всё на одном языке:
  ob_start();
  var_dump($_SERVER);
  $dump = ob_get_clean();